# rounded border around to bitmap

Tags: java, android, bitmap

```
public static Bitmap getRoundedCornerBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
    Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(),
    bitmap.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

    final int color = 0xff424242;
    final Paint paint = new Paint();
    final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
    final RectF rectF = new RectF(rect);
    final float roundPx = 12;

    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
    paint.setColor(color);
    canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF, roundPx, roundPx, paint);

    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);

    return output;
}
```

I am trying use this code for rounding bitmap, but I don't what is Mode.SRC_in and Config.ARGB_8888. I have error with them. What should I do here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For PorterDuffXfermode, you have to write `import android.graphics.PorterDuffXfermode;`

For Config.ARGB_8888, you have to write `import android.graphics.Bitmap.Config;`

Otherwise Direct press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> to organize imports.

Comment: CTRL+O to organize imports or CTRL+SHIFT+O?

Answer (score 2):

*made a oval shape xml name it to round_shape.xml*

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:shape="oval" >
    <stroke
    android:width="1dp"
    android:color="#bebebe" />
    </shape>
```

*Set this xml to background of image view like below*

```
    <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img_profile"
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:padding="2dp"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:background="@drawable/round_shape"/>
```

*Now you have round the bitmap and set as imagebitmap resource like this **img_profile.setImageBitmap(roundBit(selected_Pic_Bitmap));** , For rounding image bitmap use below code*

public Bitmap roundBit(Bitmap bm) {

```
    Bitmap circleBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm.getWidth(),
            bm.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    BitmapShader shader = new BitmapShader(bm, TileMode.CLAMP,
            TileMode.CLAMP);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setShader(shader);
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    Canvas c = new Canvas(circleBitmap);

    c.drawCircle(bm.getWidth() / 2, bm.getHeight() / 2, bm.getWidth() / 2,
            paint);

    return circleBitmap;
}
```

[image: round_image_with_border]